# Deadlock issue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I have 2 teams working in my project, one is extracting data from Table Customer & Products and the other team is trying to view the data from those tables. Both of them are performing the operation simultaneously. This is causing a deadlock. How do I solve the issue?

Comment: Both "extracting data from" and "viewing" sound like select operations however this wouldn't cause a deadlock. Please provide the table structures including indexes, the deadlocking queries and ideally the deadlock graph also.

Answer (score 0):

Use Read Committed Snapshot isolation if you are using SQL Server 2005 and above. This way your readers would not block writers.